# Create dataframe on printschema output

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a dataframe on top of parquet file and now able to see the dataframe schema.Now I want to create dataframe on top of the printschema output

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3/location")
df.printschema()
```

the output looks like [(cola , string) , (colb,string)]
Now I want to create dataframe on the output of printschema . 
What would be the best way to do that

Adding more inputs on what has been achieved so far -

```
df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://t1")
df1.printSchema()
```

We got the below result -

```
root
|-- Atp: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccetp: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccref: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccbbn: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccsdt: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccedt: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccfdt: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccddt: string (nullable = true)
|-- Ccamt: string (nullable = true)
```

We want to create dataframe with two columns - 1) colname , 2) datatype

But if we run the below code -

```
schemaRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([df1.schema.json()])
schema_df = spark.read.json(schemaRDD)

schema_df.show()
```

We are getting below output where we are getting the entire column names and datatype in a single row -

```
+--------------------+------+
|              fields|  type|
+--------------------+------+
|[[Atp,true,str...|struct|
+--------------------+------+
```

Looking for a output like

```
Atp| string 
Ccetp| string
Ccref| string
Ccbbn| string
Ccsdt| string
Ccedt| string
Ccfdt| string
Ccddt| string
Ccamt| string
```

Comment: You mean from another datasource with the schema from df?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language your are using but on pyspark I would do it like this:

```
schemaRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([df.schema.json()])
schema_df = spark.read.json(schemaRDD)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
schema_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip([col[0] for col in df1.dtypes], [col[1] for col in df1.dtypes]), schema=['colname', 'datatype'])
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).